# Does $\lim\limits_{n→∞}\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac1{\sqrt k}-2\sqrt n\right)$ exist?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Does the limit $\displaystyle\lim_{n→∞}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\dfrac1{\sqrt k}-2\sqrt n\right)$ exist? With integral test I could make this bound:
$$-2<\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{\sqrt k}-2\sqrt n\le-1.$$
How would you tackle this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you know the generalized harmonic numbers
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{k}}=H_n^{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}$$ Now, using the asymptotics of them 
$$H_n^{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}=2 \sqrt{n}+\zeta \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+\frac 1{2\sqrt{{n}}}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}\right)$$ making
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{k}}-2\sqrt{n}=\zeta \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+\frac 1{2\sqrt{{n}}}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}\right)$$  where $\zeta \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\approx -1.46035$

Let us try for $n=10$; the "exact" calculation would give $-1.30356$ while the approximation would give $-1.30224$.

Comment: So, the limit is $\zeta \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)$  ?

Comment: @ARahman. Yes, it is ! Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Put 
$$a_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac1{\sqrt{k}} -2 \sqrt{n}.$$
We have
$$a_{n+1} -a_n = \frac1{\sqrt{n+1}} -2(\sqrt{n+1} -\sqrt{n}) = \frac1{\sqrt{n+1}} -\frac{2}{\sqrt{n} + \sqrt{n+1}} = -\frac{\sqrt{n+1} -\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}(\sqrt{n+1} +\sqrt{n})}< 0.$$
Then $a_n$ is decreasing sequence. Moreover $a_n > -2$. Hence there exists the limit $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n$.