# Calculate the integral part of $\sum_{n=1}^{10^7} \frac{1}{\sqrt n}$

Tags: calculus, integration, inequality, summation, proof-writing

Calculate the integral part of 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{10^7} \frac{1}{\sqrt n}$$

and calculate
$$\sum_{n=10^4}^{10^7} \frac{1}{\sqrt n}$$
to within an error of $\frac {1}{50}$.

I have found out that $\frac{1}{\sqrt n}$ is bounded by $2(\sqrt {n+1} - \sqrt{n})$ and $2(\sqrt {n} - \sqrt{n-1})$. This would mean $\sum_{n=1}^{10^7} \frac{1}{\sqrt n}$ is between $2(\sqrt {10^7+1} - \sqrt{1})$ and $2(\sqrt {10^7} - \sqrt{0})$. How would i find the second part and to within an error of $\frac{1}{50}$.

Comment: It's exactly the same procedure, isn't it?

Comment: If you use $\sum_{n=10^4}^{10^7}\frac1{\sqrt n}=\sum_{n=1}^{10^7}\frac1{\sqrt n}-\sum_{n=1}^{10^4-1}\frac1{\sqrt n},$ what happens?  Do you get a lower bound and an upper bound that are $\le \frac{1}{50}$ apart?

Comment: You should take a look at [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2946917)

Comment: The bound for $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ is rather weak because the only information that it provides is that the the integer part of the first sum can be $6322$,$6323$, or $6324$. A slightly more helpful ( albeit still weak) lower bound for the first sum will be $2\sqrt{10^7+1}-2\sqrt{3}+1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}<S<2\sqrt{10^7}-2\sqrt{2}+1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, where S denotes the desired sum.

Comment: This tells us that the integer part of S is either $6322$ or $6323$, but I can't see how to further improve on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second sum.

By your work and by the telescopic summation we have:
$$6124.5556...<\Sigma<6124.5653...,$$ which says that $$\Sigma\approx6124.56$$
The telescoping summation gives:
$$\sum_{n=10^4}^{10^7}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}<2\sum_{n=10^4}^{10^7}(\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{n-1})=2\left(\sqrt{10^7}-\sqrt{10^4-1}\right)=6124.5653...$$ and
$$\sum_{n=10^4}^{10^7}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}>2\sum_{n=10^4}^{10^7}(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})=2\left(\sqrt{10^7+1}-\sqrt{10^4}\right)=6124.5556...$$

Comment: Can you please explain how you did the telescoping summation please?