# Limit $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} - 2\sqrt{n}\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

Let $x_n=1+\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt 3}+.......+\frac{1}{\sqrt n}-2\sqrt{n+1}$

I got to know form comment that $x_n$ is increasing sequence. is there any way to prove limit of sequence.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Note that $\sqrt{n+2}-\sqrt{n+1}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n+2}}$. Can you continue now?

Comment: Thanks a lot I got now

Comment: @richrow Dear Sir , Is it possible to calculate its limit ? Can you give me some hint

Comment: Please don't ask new questions in the comments.  Write another question instead, or since no answer has been posted to this one, you can edit it to change the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [limit $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{i}} - 2\sqrt{n}\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/109660/limit-lim-limits-n-to-infty-left-sum-limits-i-1n-frac1-sqrti-2) – the limit is the same as yours because $\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt n \to 0$.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/79115, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2946905 – all found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Clim_%7Bn%20%5Cto%20%5Cinfty%20%7D%20(%5Csum_%7Bk%3D1%7D%5En%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B%5Csqrt%20k%7D%20-%202%20%5Csqrt%7Bn%2B1%7D)%24&p=1)